# Given that $m^2+n^2=1$, $p^2+q^2=1$, and $mp+nq=0$, how much is $mn+pq$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

without using

$(m,n)\perp(p,q)$

[image]

Comment: [This Quora question has a lot of great answers](http://www.quora.com/Given-that-m-2+n-2-1-p-2+q-2-1-and-mp+nq-0-how-much-is-mn+pq). Hai Tran's solution in particular is very elementary.

Comment: I feel the Quora question may have actually been the source of your question, since the image in your question is identical to the one posted by the Quora answerer Luke Li.

Comment: @user314 you are right is that incorrect to post questions from quora to have more answers ?

Comment: @WadiaroWapoo: I have voted to close because it's unclear whether you would care about *any* answer you could receive.  This site tries to provide concise, informative Answers that will be useful to future Readers as well as the original poster.  Please read the [Help Center FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{m}{n}=-\frac{q}{p}=k\implies m=kn,\ q=-pk\\\implies n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}},\ m=\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}},\ p=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}},q=\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$$Then $mn+pq=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is obtained using trigonometry.

The condition $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ implies $x = \cos\theta$ and $y = \sin\theta$. Write
$$ m = \cos \alpha \ , \quad n = \sin\alpha $$
$$ p = \cos \beta \ , \quad q = \sin\beta $$
Then
$$ mp + nq = \cos\alpha cos\beta + \sin\alpha \sin \beta = \cos(\alpha - \beta) $$
$$ mn + pq = \cos\alpha \sin\alpha + \cos\beta \sin \beta $$

You are given that $\cos(\alpha-\beta) = mp + nq = 0$ and therefor $\alpha - \beta = \pm \pi/2$ (since $\cos(\pm \pi/2)=0$). Then $\alpha = \pi/2 + \beta$ and
Then
$$ 
mn + pq = \cos(\pi/2 + \beta) \sin(\pi/2 + \beta) + \cos\beta \sin \beta = \sin(-\beta) \cos(-\beta) + \cos\beta \sin \beta = -\sin\beta\cos\beta + \cos\beta \sin \beta = 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of angles. Assume $m=\cos\theta$ and $n=\sin\theta$. We than have $p=\cos{(\pi/2+\theta)}=-\sin\theta$ and $q=\sin{(\pi/2+\theta)}=\cos\theta$ and therefore $mn+pq=0$